# FluentNHibernate SaveOrUpdate error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using FluentNHibernate, with WebApi 2.0. I'll give a brief little introduction of what I'm trying to achieve.

So basically I have 2 tables in my Azure DB, for simplicity table 1 is `Emails` and the second table is `Events`.

So in my `EmailsController` basically the caller passes over some `JSON` data that basically constitutes of an email (i.e. Subject, Sender, etc etc).

The complication arises because in my `Emails` table, I am generating the Primary Key in code. Which is a 32 character GUID.

The Primary Key in the `Events` table is a DB Generated field with `IDENTITY`.

For performance reasons on my web app, I need to be able to store the first corresponding event to my email object.

So basically, I call `Save` on my Email object..then  a bit further down I call `Save` on my events  object. Since the PK for the `Events` table is auto generated via Azure. I am able to retrieve this, however the complication arises when I want to Edit my email object and persist it back to the DB.

I keep on getting the following error *a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*

I know *what* the error means and it's simple enough to understand, but how do I go about fixing this?

I need to store the auto generated PK from the Events object, back into another field into my Email object. Sounds simple, but can't for the life of me get this thing to work.

I've tried calling `Merge` (which was the replacement of `SaveOrUpdateCopy`) but still doesn't work. Doesn't seem to actually persist this.

I can post code for the mapping as well as my methods for calling the simple `Save` methods.

Any simple fix to this?

Comment: Do you have any relations between Emails and Events? Maybe your Event object is persisted when you persist Email object?

Comment: It's a one to many relationship. It's objects are persisted. I'm saving the email object first before calling Save on the Events object.

Comment: Does "when I want to Edit my email object and persist it back to the DB" mean that you load the formerly saved object from the db, modify it and then save it back to the db? If so, how do you load it? Perhaps this is where you get a second copy of the object with the same ID. Do you use session-per-request? What happens if you use `session.Flush()` after `session.Save()` when you first save the event and email?

Comment: I don't reload the object from the DB, the user passes in the JSON that gets mapped into my Email object. I modify some properties of it (e.g. make my PK which is the 32 character GUID). I then call `Save` on the Email object. I then modify some properties of my Event object (which I make in code). I supply the GUID as a foreign key for my Event object. I need the auto generated PK from the Event table to re-modify my Email object (because I need to update a property in it for performance reasons).

Answer (score 1):

`Save` is only for inserting a new entity. Do not use `Save` for updating an existing entity.

If the entity was loaded from your current NHibernate session, you just need to commit your transaction. There is no need to tell NHibernate you have modified it. (Or flush the session if you do not use transactions, which would be a bad thing with NH for many reasons but this is off-topic for your trouble.)

If your entity is detached from current session, you then have to attach it for update in the session by using `ISession.Update`. (It will not get updated in DB at that point. You will still have to commit your current transaction (or flush the session if you do not use transaction).)

At this point (calling `Update`), if you have the error *a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*, this means you have already loaded this entity in the session. This would looks to me like an abnormal use of the session:
Either you are saving your entity directly from a JSON de-serialization, and then you should not have already loaded it in the session you use for that. Or you first load the entity to update from session, then copy values to update on it, and finally just commit the transaction.

A quick&ugly fix for not trying to debug why you already have it in your session could be to call this before your `Update`:

```
session.Evict(session.Load<YourEntityType>(itsKey));
```

But this is just a workaround for not investigating what is actually going wrong with your code.

Comment: just tried this out. Strange, no error was thrown but my field wasn't updated.

Comment: Are you committing the transaction (or flushing session if no transaction) before checking the field is updated in your DB? (I have put it more explicitly in my answer too.)

Comment: Hello Fred, solved this issue via trigger. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: I'm not explicitly calling a `Flush` or a `Commit` before the field is updated in the DB. However, I am calling a simple `Save`. I'm then using `AutoMapper` to fetch the entity from the cache. It is the object fetched from the cache that I want to update.

Comment: You need to learn how a full blown ORM such as NHibernate works. Unit of work concept, lifecycle of entities, ... [RTFM](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html). Otherwise, go for a bare-bone micro-orm such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. When I started this project this was the only "viable" ORM. I need to learn ALOT more.

Comment: The touble is, I explain you `Save` is only for new entity, but it is like you do not get it. Maybe you think `Save` "works" for you because on entity mapped with an identity PK, it forces NHibernate to immediately flush. But no, that is just a corner case, `Save` is not for asking NHibernate to write down things into DB. This is `Flush` that is meant for this. `ITransaction.Commit` does trigger a `Flush`. If you do not either commit a transaction or explicitly `Flush` the session, your changes will not go into DB, excepted the "`Save` on identity" special case.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I have implemented the `UnitOfWork` and at the end of this entire action method which is Async, there's a `Commit`. I do know for a fact that after the `Commit` the entire transaction gets committed. However, this `Commit` like I said is at the end of the entire action method. I can post the code if you want to see...not really well versed with the entire ORM structure.